# Unreal vs real time in that example

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense

I have following sentences :

> She looks as if she is ill. //she really looks ill
>    She looks as if she was ill //she definitely is not, I am being ironic or whatever

And when I shift these into the past, I get:

> She looked as if she was ill.

From my understanding, unreal time remains the same but real time changes from present to past simple..so both will look like this.Is that correct?

And one more question, what is the difference in:

> She looked as if she has been ill.

Comment: If you want *as if* to be something unreal, use *were*.

Comment: She looked as if she were ill.

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli: I don't believe that's correct in English... because people certainly *can* become ill. I think the subjunctive is different in English than in other languages like French.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if someone really looks ill, you should just say it: "She looks ill."

If you're definite that she's not, you should say: "She looks as if she was (were) ill." You could also use "like" instead of "as if."

Change them to Past Tense and you've got:

1. She looked ill.
2. She looked as if she was (were) ill.

Finally, "She looked as if she had been ill" means "It seemed to me that she had been ill FOR QUITE SOME TIME." Not just at that particular moment I saw her. (Or that she had just recovered from an illness.)

Comment: Re your last paragraph, I think the verb disagreement in "She looked as if she has been ill" is terminal and the sentence has no clear meaning unless *looked* is changed to *looks* or *has* is changed to *had*. (Change one or the other.)

Comment: You're right, jwpat7! I missed that one. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Isn't the rule for subjunctive different in English than in e.g. French? I don't think *were* is the right term here, though please correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: Hello Mehrdad! You can use "were" after "like" ("as if") in the same way you use it after "if" and "wish." It means the idea isn't real

Comment: To me, "as if" gives a much larger sense of unreality than "like". If you say "She looked like she was ill", I am not sure whether or not she is ill, and maybe you aren't either. If you say "She looked as if she was ill", my impression is that she is unlikely to be ill.

Comment: That can be true as well, Peter. Thanks for pointing that out. "Like" being used casually, it's a bit confusing. So it's safer to be clear by using "as if"

Comment: Each to his own, isn't that the saying? I see no difference between "She looked like she was ill" and "She looked as if she was ill": neither is a subjunctive and neither describes an unreal situation. Both mean the same thing, but using "like" suggests a simile (e.g., "She looks like a lemur") and using "as if" implies unreality only if it's followed by an unreal tense, e.g., subjunctive (http://www.grammaring.com/as-if-as-though)

Comment: Each to his own, isn't that the saying? I see no difference between "She looked like she was ill" and "She looked as if she was ill": neither is a subjunctive and neither describes an unreal situation. Both mean the same thing to those who don't know standard English grammar, but using "like" (a preposition) suggests a simile (e.g., "She looks like a lemur") and using "as if" (a conjunction) implies unreality only if it's followed by an unreal tense, e.g., subjunctive (http://www.grammaring.com/as-if-as-though). English no longer has rules, only feelings.